# What is the best tool for developing and testing mobile applications using HTML5 and jQuery mobile framework?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to develop mobile applications using with html5, JavaScript and jQuery mobile framework. Please refer me which is the best SDK tool for developing and testing mobile web applications using HTML5 and jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these developing environment:

1. NetBeans.
   2.Code Lobster
2. Aptana Studios
3. Eclipse.

For testing the mobile web applications you can use this emulator:

- Ripple Emulator

This provides various environments(Devices) to test your web application. You can download this as the plugin to Google Chrome.

Here is the link: [**CHECK THIS**](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/)